# For loop not updating correctly

Tags: arrays, matlab, for-loop, conditional-statements

I have written the following code;

```
U_Velocity = [];
for aa = 1:38
    for bb = 1:38
        for cc = 1:40
            fieldname = ['U_Velocity' num2str(aa + (cc-1)*38)];
            U_Velocity.(fieldname) = dataCOMB{1,cc}{1,bb}(1:1024,2);
            MeanU_Velocity.(fieldname) = mean(dataCOMB{1,cc}{1,bb}(1:1024,2));
        end
    end
end
```

The code creates a data structure called U_Velocity. Within this structure it records 1520 data points named U_Velocity1 to 1520 correctly but it pulls the wrong data.

Currently the first 38 velocity values it pulls from the array dataCOMB are the same and are taken when cc =1 and bb=38. The second set of 38 velocity values are then the same also with cc =2 and bb=38. For some reason the for loop skips straight to the end value for bb. I'm trying to get the code to name U_velocty1 to 38 at cc=1 and bb = 1 the 2 then 3 etc up to 38.

Once the first 38 values are taken, I want the code to start again with cc now equal to 2 and bb going in increments of 1 from 1 to 38 again, this time naming the values from U_Velocity39 to 76. Any ideas what I am doing wrong here?

Regards,
Jerry

Comment: Well, for starters you should take `bb` into consideration when creating the fieldname.

Comment: For a fixed `aa`, when iterating through `bb`, the `fieldname` doesn't change. At each iteration of `bb` the content of `U_Velocity.(fieldname)` is thus overwritten, so at the end of the loop you only see the content of `bb=38`. As @sobek mentioned, you will have to take `bb` into consideration when creating the fieldname.

Comment: I figured it out. There is no need for a third for loop. bb can be = aa. see code. Thanks for the help guys! U_Velocity = [];
for aa = 1:38 
    bb = aa;
    for cc = 1:40
    fieldname = ['U_Velocity' num2str(aa + (cc-1)*38)];
    U_Velocity.(fieldname) = dataCOMB{1,cc}{1,bb}(1:1024,2);
    end
    
end

Comment: Please note that indentation alone does not declare in which loop the code should be executed. You need to set `end` correctly. I have edited your code to better highlight how it is actually executed with the `end`s set as they are.